# Robot framework, RIDE, keyword errors

Tags: robotframework, keyword

I use the following configuration for Robot Framework:

- Python 3.7.8
- Robot Framework: 4.0.2
- RIDE: 1.7.4.2

I tried the challenge of robocorp. After many attempt, I tried out the solution on the website, but a lot of keywords are not active. Despite of the fact, I imported the needed Libraries.
I copied the code in RIDE, just made one modifications: I used `*** Test Cases ***` instead of `*** Tasks ***`, because it caused an error.

The following keywords are not active:

1. Open Available Browser
2. Click Button
3. Capture Element Screenshot
4. Input Text

My code:

```
*** Settings ***

Library           Selenium2Library
Library           OperatingSystem
Library           String
Library           ExcelLibrary
Library           Collections
Library           RPA.Excel.Files    #Library    RPA.Tables
Library           RPA.Excel.Application
Library           DateTime
Library           RPA.Browser.Selenium
Library           RPA.HTTP


*** Test Cases ***

Start The Challenge

    Open Available Browser    http://rpachallenge.com/    chrome

    Download    http://rpachallenge.com/assets/downloadFiles/challenge.xlsx    overwrite=True

    Click Button    Start



Fill The Forms

    ${people}=    Get The List Of People From The Excel File

    FOR    ${person}    IN    @{people}

        Fill And Submit The Form    ${person}

    END



Collect The Results

    Capture Element Screenshot    css:div.congratulations

    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers


*** Keywords ***

Get The List Of People From The Excel File

    Open Workbook    challenge.xlsx

    ${table}=    Read Worksheet As Table    header=True

    Close Workbook

    [Return]    ${table}



Fill And Submit The Form

    [Arguments]    ${person}

    Input Text    css:input[ng-reflect-name="labelFirstName"]    ${person}[First Name]

    Input Text    css:input[ng-reflect-name="labelLastName"]    ${person}[Last Name]

    Input Text    css:input[ng-reflect-name="labelCompanyName"]    ${person}[Company Name]

    Input Text    css:input[ng-reflect-name="labelRole"]    ${person}[Role in Company]

    Input Text    css:input[ng-reflect-name="labelAddress"]    ${person}[Address]

    Input Text    css:input[ng-reflect-name="labelEmail"]    ${person}[Email]

    Input Text    css:input[ng-reflect-name="labelPhone"]    ${person}[Phone Number]

    Click Button    Submit
```

Error Message:

[ WARN ] Profiles are supported only with Chrome

[ WARN ] Profiles are supported only with Chrome

ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: Multiple keywords with name 'Capture Page Screenshot' found. Give the full name of the keyword you want to use:
RPA.Browser.Selenium.Capture Page Screenshot
Selenium2Library.Capture Page Screenshot
Start The Challenge                                                                                                                              | FAIL |
BrowserNotFoundError: Failed to start a browser:

- Chrome: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir

BrowserNotFoundError: Failed to start a browser:

- Chrome: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir

Can someone tell me, what did I wrong? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should have pasted the exact error you have.
You are using old library name for SeleniumLibrary.

You are probably wanting to use the Browser library, and you missed the installation of it.

---

*EDIT*

After uninstall, replace Selenium2Library by SeleniumLibrary.

Better not even use SeleniumLibrary if using RPA.Browser.Selenium.

More people having problems with `Open Available Browser` [here](https://forum.robocorp.com/t/no-keyword-with-name-open-available-browser-found/119).

Comment: I installed the library, but the same error occurred (also added in the description).

Comment: I installed the Browser library, (added in the description) also upgraded Selenium2Library,  but the same error occurred.